# Intellij prompting for path variables "USER_HOME_GRAILS" and "USER_HOME_GRIFFON "

Tags: intellij-idea

When I start my project in Intellij 9 (#IU-95.66) I see a red popup in the top right of my screen saying...

> Load error: undefined path variables!
>
> USER_HOME_GRAILS, USER_HOME_GRIFFON
>   are undefined. Fix it.

I do not have the Griffon/Grails plugins enabled and never have, why would I get this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The project was created with Groovy plug-in enabled and it has stored these variables in the project file. Either enable the plug-in or remove the variables from the project file.

Creating the new project should also help. We have a [related issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-54194) in our tracker, you may join it and provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

I enabled the Grails/Griffon plugin and can confirm that it solved this exact issue. I had reinstalled Intellij on another machine and this is one issue I had when starting up a project that was created under a previous install.

Thanks.!